# SQLite >= 3.8.3 version on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, sqlite3

Please, is there a simple way to install **SQLite >= 3.8.3** on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. By now, is impossible to do this via apt-get because only SQLite 3.8.2 it's available at the "Trusty" repositories.
I need a **simple way** to do this, something that simple users can do without much effort. It's because the users of my Open Source app ;)

Can someone help me throughout the **steps**?
Best regards,
Christian

Comment: see how far you can get with this. If you run into trouble edit it into the question and PM me. I'll try to update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a simple way to install SQLite >= 3.8.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

No. It is a core tool so it will not be simple. Though the instructions probably are it will be a manual task with lots of bumps.

So with that out of the way let's see how far we can get ...

Newer versions can be found on launchpad ...

- 14.10 has [3.8.6](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sqlite3).
- 15.04 has [3.8.7](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sqlite3/3.8.7.4-1).

The link has the debian installer (.DEB). Download it from one of the links and use either Ubuntu Software Center (doubleclick the downloaded file) or "dpkg" (command line) to install it. Mind though the [14.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/sqlite) and [15.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/sqlite) dependencies: it shows a minimal version for libc6. You probably will need to manually upgrade libc6 first.

Comment: Is there a way to install 3.8.6 (for example) separately, without messing with the dependencies? So there are 2 versions of sqlite3 installed? So the existing default install (3.8.2, whatever) is not touched and the other (3.8.6) that will be used only by the OP's software?

Comment: I had tried this @ypercube , but I ended up messing up the whole Linux System. The problem is that has many applications using embedded SQLite. Right now I'm looking for a way to set my application to use a specific SQLite version, independent of the Linux system, but I still don't know how to do this... Can you help?